# Use DTO Entity that is derived from EF Entity to perform insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have ASP.NET MVC website and a Class Library for Entity FrameWork

Now i need to had some data valitation using IValidatableObject.

So i have in Class Library entity framework this:

```
public class ClientA
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }      
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And in MVC project I have:

```
public class Client: ClientA, IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext){..}
}
```

But i got error make cast here:

```
Client client = new Client();
client.FirstName = "aaaa";
ClientA cl = (ClientA)client;

context.Clients.Add(cl); //error here: Type are different
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you need to map the properties from `client` to `cl` one by one.

Comment: In your original code you use inheritance as the pattern of reuse. You can also try composition for your reusage pattern. .net and java, lacking multiple inheritance, often works better with composition than inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping the objects might be preferable to casting, for example

```
ClientA c1 = new ClientA
{
    ID = client.ID,
    FirstName = client.FirstName,
    LastName = client.LastName
}
```

This of course could get very tedious, especially if you have big objects, but you could use a tool like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/), which can be a time saver when mapping objects with same named properties.

Also, as other answers have suggested, there is no need for your view model (that's what `Client` essentially is) to inherit from `ClientA`, even if they have the same properties. Validation is not a concern of class 'ClientA' and this would be more obvious with a more complex class, for example if you ever need to hide properties from the UI or address concerns like globalization/localization.

Comment: Then you should have a look at Automapper

Comment: Automapper will be about 3 lines of code to copy 1 object into another. (Two lines of code to configure two-way mapping, 1 line to do the copy)

Answer (score 1):

First answer I am going to give you.

Your instinct is wrong. The validation logic SHOULD live in your data objects in the Business Layer (not the persistence layer, perhaps your issue is that you didn't separate out BL and persistence).

This is why `IValidatableObject` lives in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and not in `System.Web`.

This way when your application is a hit and you need to port it to windows phone (pfffhahahahaha), you don't need to rewrite your validation code.

It would also allow you to <strike>override `SaveChanges()` on your DbContext to</strike><sup>1</sup> run your validation just before you save.

<sup>1</sup> You actually don't need to do that because EF already WILL do that for you...

Answer (score 1):

Use composition instead of inheritance. Most programmers after learning OOP think only in Inheritance/Polymorphism/Encapsulation.

You can instead put a thing inside another thing that validates it.

```
public abstract class Validator<T>
    : IValidatableObject 
{
    public T Value { get; }
    public abstract IEnumerable<ValidationResult> 
          Validate(ValidationContext validationContext);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is wrong for many reasons:

## Problems

### 1. Type safety

```
context.Clients.Add(cl);
```

You are trying to add a `ClientA` variable to a Client collection. This is not possible since Client is a superType of ClientA. The C# compiler cannot upcast `ClientA` variable to its super type `Client` even when `cl` actually holds a Client object. Why are you casting to ClientA anyway? It should *compile* if you add `client` variable  instead

### 2. Entity Framework

```
...Client: ClientA ...
```

This line by default will make EF treat the hierarchy as two different entities using TPH (Table per Hierarchy). This is definitely not what you are trying to achieve since you are only using `Client` as validation

### 3. Encapsulation

```
... Client: ClientA, IValidatableObject
```

As @Aron has stated validation logic is the resposability of the Client (or ClientA) class.
Therefore there should be only one class

```
public class Client : IValidatableObject
```

This class is responsible for holding its properties, validation and logic. `IValidatableObject` interface its considered a core library so feel free to implement it on your Entity

Enough with the problems now the solutions...

## Solutions

## 1. Only one Client class

```
public class Client : IValidatableObject
```

This solution is simple, well encapsulated, works great with EntityFramework and keeps logic where it should be.

This is how you must think when constructing a Domain layer

But unfortunately this layer doesn't live by itself. It should be consumed by your presentation layer and probably you were splitting this class in two because your `Validate` method contains presentation logic

So this give us the next solution...

## 2. ViewModels

```
//In your domain layer
public class Client
{
    ....
}

//In your presentation layer
public class ClientViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    //...
    // Same properties as Client
    //...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext){ ... }
}
```

Notice how ClientViewModel does not inherit from Client. It keeps the same properties as the entity but they aren't related in an inheritance hierarchy. So you have two ways of instantiating a `ClientViewModel` out of a `Client` entity.

- Manually using a Constructor, BuilderMethod, or anything else that involves calling a `new ClientViewModel()` somewhere and manually coping the properties, one by one or with reflection (Please don't do reflection)
- With a OOM (Object-Object Mapper): Being [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) one of the most popular libraries. With this option you can register a map with `Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientViewModel>();` and get a new `ClientViewModel` from a `Client` with `var clientViewModel = Mapper.Map<ClientViewModel>(client);`

Q. But wait, what about the logic in the Entity.

A. You can still make the entity an `IValidatableObject` too. that way it will handle pure domain validation, leaving the viewmodel with the UI validation.

Stay tuned for more solutions comming soon...

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOP instead of inheritance.

Look at projects like PostSharp to add your validation logic to your data class after you compile.